# Open PDF File from Download Manager Located from Download

Tags: android

I am using `DownloadManager` to download a file from `FirebaseStorage`.

First, I will get the `downloadUrl` from `FirebaseStorage` and proceed with `DownloadManager`

1. As you can see codes below, this is where after I got the `downloadUrl` as `url`.

```
downloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
val uri = Uri.parse(url)
val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)

val folderName = File.separator + "MBITION" + File.separator + fileName + fileExtension

name = folderName

Log.i("???", "url: $url")
Log.i("???", "folderName: $folderName")

request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
        folderName
 )

 enq = downloadManager!!.enqueue(request)
```

Logcat below shows the `url` and `folderName` value.

```
I/???: url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/mbition-2022.appspot.com/o/note%2F-N2_fRAhJXVshDjQMcrz?alt=media&token=936e1014-6c7a-4f46-89fd-5746eb6a9dbf
I/???: folderName: /MBITION/ICT600 - Chapter 3.pdf
```

2. As you can see codes below, where `onReceive` from `BroadcastReceiver` is handled.

```
if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE == action) {
        val downloadId = it.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0)
        val query = DownloadManager.Query()
        query.setFilterById(downloadId)
        val c: Cursor = downloadManager!!.query(query)
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
               val columnIndex: Int = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)
               if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c.getInt(columnIndex)) {

               val uriString: String = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))
               val file = File(uriString)
               val target = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

               Log.i("???", "uriString:: $uriString")
               Log.i("???", "file:: $file")

               val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                      this@NoteActivity,
                      "$packageName.provider",
                       file
               )

               target.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf")
               target.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION

               val intentChooser = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File")
               try {
                    startActivity(intentChooser)
               } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                    Tools.showToast(
                        this@NoteActivity,
                        "You need to download PDF reader"
                    )
                }
            }
         }
   }
```

Below shows the Logcat.

```
I/???: uriString:: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/MBITION/ICT600%20-%20Chapter%203-5.pdf
I/???: file:: file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/MBITION/ICT600%20-%20Chapter%203-5.pdf
```

This is my `provider_paths.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

I tried to open the file through the DownloadManager's Notification. It is working fine.

[image: DownloadManager's Notification]

Image below shows where the file is located inside the MBITION folder.

[image: Location file from MBITION folder]

Below is the error I got from Logcat.

```
2022-05-28 11:36:44.534 4999-4999/com.aaa.mbition E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.aaa.mbition, PID: 4999
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /file:/storage/emulated/0/Download/MBITION/ICT600%20-%20Chapter%203.pdf
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:800)
        at androidx.core.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:442)
        at com.aaa.mbition.ui.NoteActivity$onCompleteDownloadFile$1$onReceive$1.invoke(NoteActivity.kt:79)
```

Updated:

Refer to @blackapps 's suggestion. I tried to remove `file://` by using `replace` like below:

```
        val uriString: String = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))
        val urlFixer = uriString.replace("file://","")

        val file = File(urlFixer)
        val target = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)

        Log.i("???", "uriString:: $uriString")
        Log.i("???", "file:: $file")
        Log.i("???", "urlFixer:: $urlFixer")
                        
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
               this@NoteActivity,
               "$packageName.provider",
               file
        )
```

Below is the Logcat

```
I/???: uriString:: file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/MBITION/ICT600%20-%20Chapter%203-9.pdf
I/???: file:: /storage/emulated/0/Download/MBITION/ICT600%20-%20Chapter%203-9.pdf
I/???: urlFixer:: /storage/emulated/0/Download/MBITION/ICT600%20-%20Chapter%203-9.pdf
```

When I pressed `OK` button, it proceed to PDF Reader, a few milisecond, it kick me back to the apps.

Comment: You are messing around with that uri. It contains "%20" codes which represent spaces. Replace them. Further use File.exists() and File.canRead() before you use FileProvider.

Comment: @blackapps it is working now. Thank you! Can you share the answer and the further use also, so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @blackapps answer is working. I fixed them by using `replace`.

```
val uriString: String = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI))
val urlFixer = uriString.replace("file://", "").replace("%20", " ")
                        
val file = File(urlFixer)
val target = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
```